# How to store a webview response in local sqlite database in android?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-webview

I am trying to hit a JSON api in webview and then store the results in local sqlite Database of my app.

I also wanted to ask this is webview able to read local app data and can we put local data into a webview's settings, such as a header, cookie etc

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , Parse the json to the class object using GSON (or any other parser). class data you can use for sqlite.
GSON is for parsing the json to directly class object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at *Binding JavaScript code to Android code* section in the [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) developer guide for an explanation and example of JavaScript <-> Android Java code interaction.

Comment: I did but could get thru it as m newbie to android. Could u explain a bit more please. Thnx :)

Comment: Create a class that has a method for saving the results of the JSON api. Add an instance of that class as the JavaScriptInterface of the WebView. From within the content that you load in the WebView, call this method.

Comment: ok! i'll tweet this logic and comment on this post. Meanwhile i also wanted to ask this is webview able to read local app data and can we put local data into a webview's settings, such as a header, cookie etc